# Non-negative decomposition of a non-negative matrix

Tags: matrices, positivity

Consider a matrix $A\in{\bf M}_{n\times m}({\mathbb R})$, whose entries are non-negative. Let $r$ be the rank of $A$.

It is well-known that $A$ decomposes as $x_1y_1^T+\cdots+x_ry_r^T$ with $x_j\in{\mathbb R}^n$ and $y_i\in{\mathbb R}^m$. But is this still true if we require in addition that $x_1,\ldots,y_r$ be non-negative ?

If not, what is the minimal number $s$ of terms in such a non-negative decomposition  $x_1y_1^T+\cdots+x_sy_s^T$ ? By *minimal*, I mean that for every non-negative $n\times m$ matrix $A$ of rank $r$, a non-negative decomposition exists with $s$ terms.

Of course $s\le\min(n,m)$ works because either a row or a column is of the form $xy^T$. If $r=1$, then $s=1$ works (obvious); that is, the answer to the first question is positive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be the well-known (and difficult) task of computing [the nonnegative rank of a matrix.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonnegative_rank_%28linear_algebra%29)

It seems that the true complexity of computing the nn-rank is unknown, while verifying whether nn-rank equals actual rank is NP-Hard (the Wikipedia page comments on this).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I guessed that it should be documented. I didn't know the terminology.

Comment: @DenisSerre I think also known as factor rank

Comment: @Suvrit how about approximating $s$?